# How to keep div content visible while using Adjacent Sibling selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is making a div visible on image hover and then when hovering over the now visible div (which was hidden until image hover) keeping it visible if the pointer is within the newly visible div.

Right now I've achieved making the div appear on image hover, But once the div appears and I hover the div, it once again would not display , I want that to happen only when leaving the div (on mouseout).

The second div appears and then when moving over it, It will fade out again, what I need is for it to be visible while on hover as well, and only fade out when the pointer leaves that div.

I've added the code.

```css
.hiddenbox {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left:20%;
    top:30%;
    visibility: hidden;
    width:450px;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    outline: 9999px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    background:#fff;
  }

#image { 
  z-index:1;
  }

#image:hover~.hiddenbox {
    opacity:1;
    outline: 9999px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    visibility: visible;
  }

.hiddenbox:after, .hiddenbox:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 20%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

.hiddenbox:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 43, 79, 0);
    border-right-color: #ff2b4f;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }

.hiddenbox:before {
    border-color: rgba(135, 126, 126, 0);
    border-right-color: #877e7e
    border-width: 0px;
    margin-top: -16px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
<div class="hiddenbox"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"></div>
```

Comment: Can you not make it a child element?

Comment: @Leothelion That does not work because , when hovering over the hidden div itself the div appears, below the image div, So that won't work.

Comment: @PaulRedmond Yeah, it doesn't have to be a child element, But how will it work that way?

Comment: You mean it doesn't have to be a sibling, it can be a child?

Comment: It can be a child, I've tried with jquery but the same issue persists, The div wont stay visible when hovering over it after making it visible. What am I missing?

Comment: If it is a child, any `:hover` rule of the parent will automatically be triggered by hovering child elements. It's called *event bubbling* .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of your comments saying that it can be a child div, I put the hiddenbox div inside the image div after the image, and changed the selector "#image:hover~.hiddenbox" to "#image:hover .hiddenbox".

```css
.hiddenbox {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left:20%;
    top:30%;
    visibility: hidden;
    width:450px;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    outline: 9999px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    background:#fff;
  }

#image { 
  z-index:1;
  display: inline-block;
  }

#image:hover .hiddenbox {
    opacity:1;
    outline: 9999px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    visibility: visible;
  }

.hiddenbox:after, .hiddenbox:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 20%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

.hiddenbox:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 43, 79, 0);
    border-right-color: #ff2b4f;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }

.hiddenbox:before {
    border-color: rgba(135, 126, 126, 0);
    border-right-color: #877e7e
    border-width: 0px;
    margin-top: -16px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="hiddenbox">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When hovering over the white space outside the "image" div the hidden div appears , that's the issue, it should'nt happen that way

Comment: I see. I have added a display of inline-block to the #image div to achieve that result.

Comment: Thanks, Works great!